# JFreeChart border line for areas?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a dynamic XYAreaChart and I want line borders to be clear because the area is all filled with a gradient color but I want the line borders to be in different color, for example my area is filled with gradient green and red color and I want the line borders to be in black color. How to do this?

Here's my code:

```
final XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Data");

    XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);

    // Creation du area chart
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYAreaChart("Fun Meter", "", "",
            dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, false, false);


    // jframe=new ChartFrame("Fun Meter", chart);

    ChartPanel CP = new ChartPanel(chart);

    XYPlot xyPlot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();



    GradientPaint gp0 = new GradientPaint(0.0f, 100.0f, new Color(50, 205,
            50), 0.0f, 100.0f, Color.red);

    xyPlot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(0, gp0);

    xyPlot.setForegroundAlpha(0.75f);
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) & [screenshot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: Ok trashgod it's done

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `setSeriesOutlinePaint(int, Paint)` method on the renderer.
Assuming you use a `XYAreaRenderer`
So something like:

```
XYAreaRenderer renderer = (XYAreaRenderer) xyPlot.getRenderer();
renderer.setSeriesOutlinePaint(0, Color.black);
renderer.setSeriesOutlineStroke(0, new BasicStroke(0.5f));
renderer.setOutline(true);
```

Comment: In addition to the ouline paint, you probably need to set the outline stroke.